# Can you hit the level cap if recruit adventurers as soon as you hit Black Hound Inn? (PoE patch 1.5)

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I've started my second attempt at a playthrough, the first ending right after I got my stronghold, because I realized that all of the characters I liked using were glass cannons.

Now I've just reached the Black Hound Inn and am going to create a tank (leaning Barbarian) so that I have two tanks and four glass cannons.

My question is this: If I create an adventurer - and thus have an "extra" party member from the time I hit Gilded Vale until I'd be able to have a full party of developer-made characters - will I still be able to hit the level cap? I'm a completionist, and aim to do every quest and dungeon I can find, but it seems like the extra character would drain a lot of early-game XP.

Edit: This is **not** a duplicate question. The last time XP was asked about was in version 1.3. Version 1.5 specifically states that they lowered the amount of available XP in order to delay people getting to the level cap.

Comment: You can hit level-cap on whatever patch, having full party early doesn't have much effect on this

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to murder anything that breaths (or at least most of it), complete the stronghold missions and complete the bounties, you'll hit the level cap well before the end of the game on easy.